# Simple Django form with autocomplete

Tags: jquery, django, autocomplete

Is there any simple example on how to use autocomplete in Django forms:

```
forms.py
class SimpleForm(forms.form):
    a = forms.ModelChoiceField(Model.objects)

template
form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ simple_form }}
```

And i need a field to be autocomplete. I found [this](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/tree/master/test_project/non_admin), but this is a Model form not a normal form.
Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) has a very easy integration with django. You just need to create a function which returns a json with your query. For example:

```
def automcomplete(request):
    search_qs = YourObject.objects.filter(title__icontains=request.REQUEST['search'])[:5]
    results = []
    for r in search_qs:
        results.append(r.title)
    resp = request.REQUEST['callback'] + '(' +simplejson.dumps(results) + ');'
    return HttpResponse(resp,content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code I used for Django 3.2:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def my_autocomplete(request):
    """Return a json list of suggestions given a prefix in 'term' param"""
    term = request.GET.get('term', None)

    qs = MyObject.objects.all()
    if term:
        qs = qs.filter(field__istartswith=term)
    # NOTE: This order is non-deterministic if there are more than 5
    # objects with the same 'order'.  I'm assuming that's okay.
    qs = qs.order_by('order')[:5]

    results = [r.field for r in qs]

    # NOTE: results is put into json.  safe=False allows an array.
    return JsonResponse(results, safe=False)
```